# Why can't I access my RabbitMQ broker on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to communicate with my RabbitMQ server using a C# .NET Core 3.1 client. If I run a RabbitMQ server on my local machine, it works fine. If I try to do the same on the RabbitMQ server I started on AWS, I cannot reach it.

C# client:

```
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            HostName = amqp.Server,
            UserName = amqp.Username,
            Password = amqp.Password,
            Port = amqp.Port
        };

        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

I checked the values of amqp.Server, Username, Password and Port and all of them are correct. Anyways, it returns the following exception:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
> ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)
> ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
> ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

First I thought, the AWS firewall may block requests from the used port (5671, AMQPs), but trying to connect using Telnet worked.

Screenshot of the current ACL settings:
[image]

Same setting is used for Outbound rules too. But to be honest I am not sure whether I have to use TCP or another traffic type.

EDIT: Access type is set to "Public access". I forgot to say that. My apologies.

Does anyone have an idea what to try?

EDIT2: Here's the output of the CLI command list-brokers:
[image]

Comment: You refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-high-latency-on-alb/) from AWS to troubleshoot such issues.

Comment: @theoneandonlyprogrammer it depends how you have launched your mq server [public or private](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-mq-update-new-rabbitmq-message-broker-service/)

Comment: @samtoddler I set "Access type" to Public access if it's that what you mean. Sorry, forgot to say that in my question. I will edit it now.

Comment: curious if you have created the necessary brokers as well as per the post, if yes please share the output of [list-brokers](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/mq/index.html) command as well.

Comment: @samtoddler I just added a screenshot of the output in the question. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I launched a single node broker while making sure the access is set to public and it is launched inside the public subnet of the VPC and I am able connect. [Example here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/7b7bfdfdfcff1db5ce21b8587b6cee0d)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I tried to run your code and received a AMQPConnectionError exception. If I try to use this with my local AMQP server, it works as expected. With AWS it returns the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Our company firewall blocked the port 5671. Now it works.
Thank you for your help @samtoddler and @amitd.